# Open modal each item of array Angular

Tags: angular, modal-dialog

I have a series of lists and I am trying to make it so every time I click on an item of the list, a modal window opens with the information of the item that has been clicked. I would like to do it only with a modal that changes the information, so as not to have to add a modal for each item in the array. Can anyone give some information on how it could be planned?

html:

```
<ul class="c-list">
    <li *ngFor="let item of text.list" class="c-list-item">
        <button type="button" class="c-list-item__button">
            <div class="c-list-item__image" aria-hidden="true">
                <img [src]="item.image" [alt]="" loading="lazy" />
            </div>
            <p class="c-list-item__name">{{ item.name }}</p>
            <p class="c-list-item__surname">{{ item.surname }}</p>
        </button>
    </li>
</ul>
```

ts:

```
list = [
    {
      image: '/../assets/people-one.png',
      name: 'people one',
      surname: 'one'
    },
    {
      image: '/../assets/people-second.png',
      name: 'people second',
      surname: 'second'
    },
    {
      image: '/../assets/people-third.png',
      name: 'people third',
      surname: 'third'
    }
];
```

The modal would show the image, name and surname and an explanatory text of each item.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to create a new component:

```html
import { Component, Inject, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MAT_DIALOG_DATA, MatDialogRef } from '@angular/material/dialog';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-modal',
  template: `
       <h1 mat-dialog-title>Hi {{data.name}}</h1>
       <div mat-dialog-content>
         <div>data.name</p>
         <div>data.surname</p>
         <img [src]="data.image"/>
       </div>
       <div mat-dialog-actions>
         <button mat-button (click)="onClose()">Ok</button>
       </div>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./app-modal.component.scss'],
})
export class ModalComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(
    private dialogRef: MatDialogRef<ModalComponent>,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: { image:string,name:string,surname:string }
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {}

  onClose() {
    this.dialogRef.close();
  }

}
```

And in your component you need to have something like this:

```
constructor(private dialog:MatDialog){}

onClick(item:any){
   this.dialog
   .open(ModalComponent, {
    autoFocus: false,
    width: '450px',
    data:item,
   })
   .afterClosed()
   .subscribe();
}
```

On the button tag you should call **onClick** method:

<button (click)="onClick(item)" ...

Comment: You need to declare `MatDialogModule` to imports. 
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    // ...
    MatDialogModule
  ],
...
})
export class YourModule {}